# Bootstrap Toggle open menu on hover and close on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, toggle

I have toggle button with dropdown menu, where my requirement is:

- Dropdown should open on hover, but should not close again when mouse leave from there (on mouseleve)
- Dropdown should close on click on the close button which display after opening dropdown menu

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row pull-right hamburger-position">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So how I can maintain these both scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I have added some jQuery and it's working now !

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
            if ($('.dropdown-menu').css('display') == 'block') {
                $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'none');
            } else {
                $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');
            }
        });

        $('.dropdown-toggle').mouseover(function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');
        })
    });
```

**But still I want to do it with just AngularJS....!**

And one more requirement is:
* On opening of dropdown toggle button should replace with close button (x)

Answer (score 0):

Please write some example code from your side which you try to make something as you want. Because,

**[PRACTICE MAKES PERFECT] :)**

```js
$('.hamburger-position .my-dropdown').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('open').css({
    'border':'1px solid red'
  });
});
```

```css
.my-dropdown{
  width:auto;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row hamburger-position">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="dropdown my-dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: dropdown is not closing on click.

Comment: As you see On Hover dropdown is visible, now if you want to close dropdown on clicking on the links[eg.: HTML, CSS] - have to write jquery/javascript code to remove open class from [.dropdown] class.

Comment: Yes exactly...!